# I can not connect socket from android clien to java server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want connect Android client to java server. My android client  on real phone and server on localhost. I tried connect but shows error:

```
09-28 11:08:44.399  14330-14371/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets, PID: 14330
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
            at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I set android permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This my code:

```
private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mSocket = new Socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL, 4444);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyAsync myAsync = new MyAsync();
        myAsync.execute();
    }
```

And it is server host:

```
public static final String CHAT_SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.0.33";
```

And

[image]

I tried open this ip in browser on phone - opens a blank page and no error.
If i tried connect from Java core client on my computer - all good. It means that server work good. I tried connect from android emulator with 10.0.0.2 ip - not helped.

**EDIT**
I add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and app not crush but error

```
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://192.168.0.33": No address associated with hostname
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:109)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:65)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:61)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
09-28 11:36:36.829  28006-28046/smsagent.sedi.ru.sockets W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
```

Comment: Is the port No correct?

Comment: Make sure any firewall is not restricting the connections from external ips.

Comment: How should I know? I ordered all things right, but does not work, so I ask

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to write that the firewall is disabled

Comment: add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> also in the manifest file . check for the case use in your code.

Comment: @ WannaBeGeek you read questions or just answer ? I added permissions

Comment: @Pavel you added them later .

Comment: @ WannaBeGeek added it before EDIT

Comment: @Pavel you had <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" /> whereas it was supposed to be this: add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> . I ask you check for use case .

Comment: @ WannaBeGeek do you really think it's important ??? This style of writing generate android Studio

Comment: @Pavel it is case sensitive statement . You can try again with ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET . You will get the error again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Use 192.168.0.33 instead of 192.168.0.33
192.168.0.33 is URL ,and 192.168.0.33 is IP.

Comment: Use 192.168.0.33 instead of http://192.168.0.33. http://192.168.0.33 is URL ,and 192.168.0.33 is IP.

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.33 (port 4444): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Comment: InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.33");
            Socket socket=new Socket(serverAddr,4444);

Comment: I found error. If i use 10.0.2.2 instead 10.0.0.2 all work/ Now i work with emulator